# Exporting large amount of data from from Hive using PySpark

Tags: hive, apache-spark-sql, pyspark

I'm new to PySpark and I wonder what is the best practice for exporting large amount of data from Hive using PySpark?

I have a SQL query that retrieves a huge amount of data\results and I want to export them to another machine for further processing.

How to do this in the quickest way?

I know that I can use "collect" but since this is a huge amount of data I'll run out of memory pretty fast...

Comment: What's the other machine? Is it another database, or something like R

Comment: You can maybe create a stream, like Kafka, and send it over that way. On the other side, you can use Spark stream to read it.

Comment: The other machine is windows machine.